# Data truncated - $faker->randomElements

Tags: laravel

I created a factory and want to generate randomElements from an array. However, when I run the factory in tinker I get "Array to string conversion error". Can someone explain why?

This is the column in the table

```
$table->enum('interest_tags', ['php', 'javascript', 'vue']);
```

And I generate randomElements from the array like this:

```
'interest_tags' => $faker->randomElements(['php', 'javascript', 'vue'], 2),
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data in **comma separated** format in your DB.

```
'interest_tags' => implode(",", $faker->randomElements(['php', 'javascript', 'vue'], 2))
```

In your Model::class you can create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) like

```
public function getInterestTagsAttribute($value)
{
    return explode(",", $value); // php,vue  -->  ['php', 'vue']
}
```

Or if you planning to store just one item then use randomElement()

```
 @method mixed randomElement(array $array = array('a', 'b', 'c'))
 @method array randomElements(array $array = array('a', 'b', 'c'), $count = 1, $allowDuplicates = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

`randomElements` function returns a array. He size is the second parameter. 
In your case the return its something like:

```
['php','vue]
```

But you cant store a array in database. You only can store a string.
See `randomElement` method, he return a only one element, like:

```
'php'
```